# Custom function does not work properly unless the object is stored in the global environment in R

Tags: r, tidyeval, nse, non-standard-evaluation

**Context**

I have a custom function `myfun1` that fits the cox model. Before fitting the model, I need to do a bit of processing on the data used to fit the model. Specifically, run two lines of code, `dd = datadist(data)` and `options(datadist = 'dd')`.

If `dd` exists in the *environment inside the function*, `myfun1` will report an error.

But when I output `dd` to the *global environment*, `myfun2` works fine.

**Question**

Why does this happen?

How can I get `myfun1` to run properly while keeping `dd` inside the function?

**Reproducible code**

```
library(survival)
library(rms)
data(cancer)

myfun1 <- function(data, x){
  
  x = sym(x)
  
  dd = datadist(data)
  options(datadist = 'dd')
  
  fit = rlang::inject(cph(Surv(time, status) ~ rcs(!!x), data = data))
  
  fit
}

myfun1(dat = lung, x = 'meal.cal')

# Error in Design(data, formula, specials = c("strat", "strata")) : 
#   dataset dd not found for options(datadist=)

myfun2 <- function(data, x){
  
  x = sym(x)
  
  dd <<- datadist(data) # Changed here compared to myfun1
  options(datadist = 'dd')
  
  fit = rlang::inject(cph(Surv(time, status) ~ rcs(!!x), data = data))
  
  fit
}

myfun2(dat = lung, x = 'meal.cal')

# Frequencies of Missing Values Due to Each Variable
# Surv(time, status)           meal.cal 
# 0                 47 
# 
# Cox Proportional Hazards Model
# 
# cph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ rcs(meal.cal), data = data)
# 
# 
# Model Tests    Discrimination    
# Indexes    
# Obs        181    LR chi2      0.72    R2       0.004    
# Events     134    d.f.            4    R2(4,181)0.000    
# Center -0.3714    Pr(> chi2) 0.9485    R2(4,134)0.000    
# Score chi2   0.76    Dxy      0.048    
# Pr(> chi2) 0.9443
```

Comment: I am not sure about your question. Why is dd between quotes in options? Without quotes executes well.

Comment: @Colibri. In the document of `datadist()` and `cph()`, The author of `rms` package used quoted `dd` in `options()`, so I used the same code. It's weird that when I use `options(datadist = dd)` without quotes, `myfun1()` works fine.

Comment: Probably a quoted name is a convenience that means "look for that object in the global env".